# Flutter app run Cannot invoke method toInteger() on null object

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter. I have just cloned a project on GitHub that I have to work on. So running the project first in my android studio brings me the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\19ngu\AndroidStudioProjects\damufasta\android\app\build.gradle' line: 29
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Cannot invoke method toInteger() on null object

I have already resolved the dependencies and pointed the project SDK and module to the latest API as directed from checking other responses. So I was expecting it to run successfully.

This is the app\build.gradle file content:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.damufasta"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Can you please share with us your `android\app\build.gradle'` content? that may help us to help you

Comment: Sorry for the delay @daniel. That is the build.gradle file added to the question. It appears I was missing values in the local properties file. That is where the null was coming from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set min sdk at 21 :

minSdkVersion = 21 Line 44 build.gradle

Answer (score 3):

In case this happens, one of the likely problems as mentioned by the responders is the missing value of the `minSdkVersion` in the `local.properties` file.

So first check if the values are present, if not add them.

If they are present then ensure that the `minSdkVersion is 21`.

This has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go this path

```
\your_project_name\android\app\build.gradle
```

and Open this file `build.gradle` changed

```
defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 21

    }
```